# Yoast SEO Inserting H1 into page. Can't figure out how to remove it

Tags: seo, wordpress

I have a custom theme created and I installed the Yoast SEO plugin (wordpress seo). When I did that it took the "SEO Title" and put it in an H1 towards the top of my page. I want to remove this as it doesn't fit in with the theme.

Does anyone know how I can do this? I can show you what I am talking about if you need that?

Comment: Search/ask the pluggin's forum.

Comment: I did and haven't gotten a response. I came here after trying that and getting nothing.

Comment: This is a plugin specific question and I think only users who have used it can answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to delete the h1 tag that was being generated by default in the template I was using. Just did it from the editor in the wordpress back end.